Repair or replace beam that has wood rot?
I have this a beam on my front porch that is rotting. It looks like the previous owners had problems with wood rot as well but just filled it with foam insulation. I'm wondering what options I have to fix this. As shown in the pictures the wood rot had already gotten pretty deep so I'm not sure I can just bondo this. Is replacing the beam the only option to really address this?



What that post is holding up looks pretty beefy. I would replace it.

Repair might be possible, but replacement is recommended.  Rot usually requires moisture getting into wood, so checking for water leaks above will help.  Would also check for wood bugs/wood peckers, since rot is usually found at the bottom.

That seam in the rain gutter just above gives the impression water that has  leaked through the gutter seam contributed to the rot.  After replacing the post, consider adding some flashing.

Structural. Replace.

Fortunately, it looks like that post is only holding up the beam in compression.  You should be able to support the beam in some other fashion temporarily (jacking posts? can't say without additional info) and cut out the rotted part and replace with good material.
